# Problems with startActivityForResult/onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to check a value on some activities calls.
This is what I'm trying to do:

Activities A, B, C

A -> B -> C

In A I need to check a value that is seted in C.
By that I startActivityFromResult(B), and in B startActivityFromResult(C).
In B the Intent data!=null, but in A, the Intent data from B is null.

Is ok this approach? Or I need to implement another way?

Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to check\get some value, that doesn't creates by user, then you can just make some static fields. There is no need to start this activity.

But if you sure that this is what you are really want, then add values from your activity B to  Intent and then start C for result. Same thing with C activity.